# Tikz - How to nest nodes in a matrix so they can be connected?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, nesting

I want to make a matrix which has multiple nodes in a single matrix cell. These nodes should be centered to each other. I managed to make this work by using a nested tikz environment like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, semithick]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
        minimum width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum
        height=4em] 

    \matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep = 2em,
    nodes={anchor=center}
    ] (mx2){
        % First row:
        label1
        & 
        \node{\tikz{
            \node[block](n1){node1}; 
            \node[block, right=of n1](n2){node2}; 
        }};
        \\
        % Second row:
        label2
        &
        \node{\tikz{
            \node[block] (n3) 
            {node 3};
            \node[block] (n4) [right=of n3] 
            {node 4};
            \node[block] (n5) [right=of n4] 
            {node 5};
        }};
        \\
        };
    \draw (n1) -- (n4); % this fails
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now connecting these nodes is impossible because of the nested tikz environments. I have tried to get a similar image using the `fit` library, but I did not manage to make it work. Can any of you help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just upload the image but the remove the `!` character in the front. We will fix it for you until you get enough rep points to do it.

Comment: I upvoted. Now you must be able to upload the figure. pl. try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general one can use the `remember picture` option and apply it *all* pictures, that should be accessible later. Since your pictures are nested and the options are inheritable, it’s sufficient to apply `remember picture` only to the upper level `{tikzpicture}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, semithick, remember picture,
    block/.style={rectangle, draw, 
        minimum width=5em, text centered, rounded corners,
        minimum height=4em, text width=5em}
    ]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep = 2em,
    nodes={anchor=center}
    ] (mx2){
        % First row:
        label1
        & 
        \node{\tikz{
            \node[block] (n1) {node1}; 
            \node[block, right=of n1] (n2) {node2}; 
        }};
        \\
        % Second row:
        label2
        &
        \node{\tikz{
            \node[block] (n3) {node 3};
            \node[block] (n4) [right=of n3] {node 4};
            \node[block] (n5) [right=of n4] {node 5};
        }};
        \\
    };
    \draw (n1) -- (n4); % this works
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Compile twice to get the right result.

Note that I replaced `\tikzstyle{block}` by `block/.style` which is the preferred way. See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Comment: Looks like `remember picture` is inherited: your first nested node doesn't have it and yet the position is computed correctly.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I realized it my self a few second ago. I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes !! another possibility of nested pictures.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I removed my `\tikzstle` macros, thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think `matrix` library is redundant here (though I'm abusing it continuously). Straight forward use is also possible and (in my opinion) more convenient. The `positioning` library is used anyway so we can keep on relying on that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={rectangle, draw, 
        minimum width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum
        height=4em,text width=5em}
    ]
\node (l1) at (0,2) {label 1};
\node (l2) at (0,0) {label 2};
\node[right = 2.5cm of l1,block] (n1) {Node 1};
\node[right = of n1,block] (n2) {Node 2};
\node[right = 1cm of l2,block] (n3) {Node 3};
\node[right = of n3,block] (n4) {Node 4};
\node[block,right=of n4] (n5) {node 5};
\draw (n1) -- (n4); % this fails not :)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can keep track of individual positioning and the default settings by `node distance` option and `<direction> = x cm of nodename` just as you would need to do by `row sep` and `column sep` when using matrices.

[image]

---

*EDIT* As Altermundus commented you can stack your rows by centering on a predefined grid of coordinates

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={rectangle, draw, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em}
    ]
\foreach \x in {0,...,2} \node[circle,inner sep=1mm,fill] (cent\x) at (2,2*\x) {}; 
%The center goes in between
\node[right=of cent0,block] (n1) {A very wide node 1};
\node[left =of cent0,block] (n2) {2};
%The center hits the node
\node[block] at (cent1) (n4) {node 4};
\node[block,left =of n4] (n3) {Also a quite wide node 3};
\node[block,right=of n4] (n5) {5};
\draw (n1) -- (n4); % this fails not :)
%This uses eyeballing after compiling. Choose the widest and adjust.Can be absolute too.
\node[left= of n3] (l2) {label 2};
\node (l1) at (l2 |- cent0){label 1};
\node (l3) at (l2 |- cent2){label 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to center the nodes automatically. In my diagram the nodes have varying widths and I would like to have the whole group centered. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Ruben In which direction do you want to center them, when the node is full vertically or centering horizontally with respect to other nodes?

Comment: I would like to horizontally move _Node 1_ and _Node 2_ together to the center of  _Node 3_, _Node 4_ and _Node 5_. The distance between the nodes of the group should stay the same and the whole group should move horizontally to the center of the other group.

Comment: I think I understood. But you have used the `text width=5em` option which fixes the width. So I guess you are solving your own problem anyway :) Just put a long text in one of the nodes.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that. That was actually part of my debug efforts. This is not in the final diagram. Sorry for the confusion. But I take it your solution does not work for variable width nodes?

Comment: @Ruben Let me come up with an example and see if it addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the nested pictures

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, semithick,remember picture,
    block/.style={rectangle, draw, 
        minimum width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum
        height=4em,text width=5em}
    ]

    \matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep = 2em,
    nodes={anchor=center}
    ] (mx2){
        % First row:
        label1
        & 
          \node[block,right=1em,anchor=west](n1){node1}; 
          \node[block, right=of n1](n2){node2};         
        \\
        % Second row:
        label2
        &
            \node[block] (n3) {node 3};
            \node[block] (n4) [right=of n3] {node 4};
            \node[block] (n5) [right=of n4]  {node 5};
        \\
    };
    \draw (n1) -- (n4); % this fails
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: does this work when I have nodes of varying width?

Comment: If all you nodes have different width, I change the method. First with a matrix or a grid, I will define some coordinates ( centers of future nodes ) and then I place the nodes centered on these coordinates. Perhaps something like percusse's answer. It's difficult to give an answer without to see the real problem.